# $A$ is irreducible doubly non-negative, then $rank(A) \geq n-1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Let $A = D + 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & F \\
    F^T & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ be in the block form, where $D$ is diagonal and $F$ is $k \times (n-k)$. Let $A$ be doubly non-negative, i.e. both non-negative entry wise and positive semi definite. Then $D^{- \frac12}AD^{- \frac12}$ is also doubly non-negative.

$$D^{- \frac12}AD^{- \frac12} = \begin{bmatrix}
    I_k & C \\
    C^T & I_{n-k} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$, where $C$ is $k \times (n-k)$.

Further more if $A$ is irreducible doubly non-negative, then to prove that $rank(A) \geq n-1$.

I am not getting clue how to proceed.

Comment: The question looks strange. If $A$ is positive definite, it must have rank $n$. Do you mean $A$ is positive **semi**definite instead?